# Single changelog from multiple Git repos

Tags: git, changelog

I don't know if this has already been answered, but I couldn't find an answer for my problem.
Example scenario is something like this:

Developer 1 works on **project A**

Developer 2 works on **project B**

Both developers work on **project C** *(where shared libraries reside)*

Developer 1 wants to generate a log from commits of **project A** and **project C** *(commits made by him)*

I have seen custom scripts making this but I want to know if there's a way to do this using **Git** *(windows)* only.

Comment: are you saying the all projects are in different git repositories?

Comment: yes they are independent

Comment: there is no native git feature which would allow you that. submodules will not help here. 'subree' might work. also have a look at git 'subrepo'.

Comment: @Serge subtree solved my problem. Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @ Sinan Çetinkaya Good to know that it worked for you. I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git itself has no convenient way to do what you want. There is definitely a set of functions which, if used correctly, can do what you want. Fortunately few git extensions already implement the functionality.

Git `subtree` is a part of git distribution package and allows to map another project repo into your main project repo. It allows mapping histories between the main and project and the sub-projects. It seems to be a good candidate to solving your issues.

It is implemented as a very simple script and has some disadvantages. For example, the mapping information is not passed through the clones. This had been solved with 'git-subrepo' script. So, this could be a second candidate for you.

Git submodules do not provide history mapping and most likely would be difficult to use in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If the developer doesn't want to mix stuff up, they could set up a new project and link the remotes of those two repos and then they could run: `git log --all --author="my name"`. That should give the log for all the branches on both projects.

Comment: git log --all --author="my name" shows commits from project A only, not from project C

Comment: yes I did. I've got answer from another developer he said, there's no such thing in Git, I have to add project C as submodule

Comment: submodules have separate histories, so they will not work for you.

Comment: You can have multiple repos (remotes) set up on a single repo... and there's no rule that they have to belong to the same project... under normal circumstances it's not the best idea to have unrelated stuff on a single repo but given that you want to see the history of two unrelated repos in a single shot, the best you can do is set up two remotes on a repo (like I said on my recipe). So, read `git help remote` and them add whatever repos you need to a single repo (with `git remote add`) and then fetch them all and run `git log --all --author="who am i"` and be happy.

Comment: Prepend all those statements with a _please_ so that it doesn't sound so bossy.... please. :-D

Comment: @eftshift0 it's all ok. I was just wondering that if there's a built-in way in Git to merge logs from both repos. Running a third repo is less practical than writing a script to merge logs and sort by commit dates.